# Sending CURL post in swift

Tags: ios, swift, curl, post

I'm trying to use an API in my iOS app but I do not know much about curl or post methods.

The API takes input in this form.

```
  curl https://www.onradar.com/api/v1/geofences \
    -H "Authorization: org_live_sk_108c97506e7549bdbffd68cc4512a7df1fc1c469" \
    -X POST \
    -d "description=Monk's Café" \
    -d "tag=venue" \
    -d "externalId=2" \
    -d "type=circle" \
    -d "coordinates=[-73.975363, 40.783826]" \
    -d "radius=50"
```

Is there a native way to perform a curl post in Swift or do I have to use something like Alamofire?

Here is what I'm trying with no success.

```
 func curlPost(){
    let url: URL = URL(string: "https://www.onradar.com/api/v1/geofences")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.addValue("org_live_sk_108c97506e7549bdbffd68cc4512a7df1fc1c469", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let params = "d \"description=Monk's Café\" -d \"tag=venue\" -d \"externalId=2\" -d \"type=circle\" -d \"coordinates=[-73.975363, 40.783826]\" -d \"radius=50\""
    request.httpBody = params.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    _ = session.dataTask(with: request)
}
```

Comment: `curl post` isn't a thing. cURL is a command line tool for transferring data over (among other things) http. Many other libraries can do that, such as Alamofire or NSURLSessions.

Comment: I'm trying NSURLSessions but still no luck.  I've updated my post to show my code.

Comment: Your params looks like wrong format, I think it should just be "key=value&key2=value2" and encode it with utf8

Comment: You're right. Switching from curl interpretation to standard http post is what confused me.